# Xcode 6.3&Swift ERROR:Objective-C method 'init' defined by implicit initializer 'init()' here

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just updated to Xcode 6.3 beta. It supports Swift 1.2 and so it makes my project many errors. Although I have used the "Convert To Swift 1.2" function, but it can't clear all errors. such as this error:

```
import SpriteKit
class Score: Shape {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name:"Score",imageName:"score")
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
        light.lightColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        light.categoryBitMask = scoreLightCategory
    }
}
```

Xcode shows there is an error in 3rd line: Initializer 'init()' overrides Objective-C method 'init' from superclass 'SKSpriteNode'; Objective-C method 'init' defined by implicit initializer 'init()' here

But if I add parameters like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class Score: Shape {
    convenience init(args:Bool) {
        self.init(name:"Score",imageName:"score")
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
        light.lightColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        light.categoryBitMask = scoreLightCategory
    }
}
```

But what does "Objective-C method 'init' defined by implicit initializer 'init()' here" mean? How can I solve this problem gracefully?

PS: The `Shape` class inherits from `SKSpriteNode` class:

```
class Shape: SKSpriteNode {
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    init(name:String,imageName:String){

        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName),color:SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(radius*2, radius*2))
        self.name = name
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I hope somebody else can help you.

Comment: Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default. So  `init()` is a designated initializer of  `SKSpriteNode`  in Objc, but not in Swift. I think this issue broke the bridge between Objc and Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved in Xcode 6.3 beta 2. After cleaning the build folder and rebuilding, it runs with no error.